# Will serial calls to Threading.Timer.Change() reset the timer's clock?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

If I call [`Threading.Timer.Change()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx) twice in a row, when will the thread next run?

For example:

```
myTimer.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);
// Only 2 seconds pass.
myTimer.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

After this, will the thread next run in 3 seconds or 5 seconds?

I hope the answer is the latter, that the timer is reset with each call of `Change()`. If not, I'll need to find a way around this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will run in 5 seconds.  Calling Change will Reset the initial Count.

Answer (score 1):

Not according to this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/0cce7729-be65-45da-a9e2-bda3893d84f2
It says your timer callback may get called when you call Change().